Can Mereology account for vagueness as a fundamental property of parts?
I'm new to the study of mereology, and my approach has primarily been through Husserl's Third Logical Investigation.
I want to know if it's possible to construct a "universe" (I believe that's the term) where vagueness is a fundamental property of the parts. In other words, rather than denying the existence of parts in which wholes consist, it’s that, ontologically, the boundaries between the parts are in re vague.
Clear boundaries would only emerge in wholes made up of conventionally imputed parts, nominally determined.
This does not mean that what eliminates vagueness is merely our own de dicto imputation, but rather that whenever there is a clear boundary, it is linked to our nominal designation. The parts must be susceptible to being designated in this way, meaning that not just any vague part fits any nominally imposed boundary.
Is there any way to express this mereologically?
Thanks, and I apologize for the possible vagueness of the question.

I think it would be interesting to explore vagueness with respect to mereology, but I can't think of anything in the standard mereology theories that really implies perfect precision. Mereotopology arguably does because it deals specifically with boundaries and assumes boundaries are perfectly precise.

Ontological (in re) vagueness generally, and mereological in particular, are usually considered problematic, see e.g. Eklund's discussion. However, some possibilities are considered in Donnelly, Mereological Vagueness and Existential Vagueness.

You say:

I want to know if it's possible to construct a "universe" (I believe that's the term) where vagueness is a fundamental property of the parts.

Let's be very clear that vagueness (SEP) is a not a property of parts of the mereological system de re, but rather the language used to construct it. That is to say, ambiguity and vagueness are indeterminate references, as in the sense of sense and reference. When we say, I don't know which one, that is because there is not enough language to determine which one.
Vagueness is a feature of language and even in simple sign systems it cannot entirely be eliminated, but is generally minimized to a degree; the opposite of vagueness is precision. InThe Philosophy of Language (GB) by Szabó and Thomason, they have this to say in 13.3.31 on page 284:

A sentence can contain indexicals and we may be uncertain about the context, or it can be ambiguous and we can be uncertain about which of several sense is play. Vagueness also induces uncertainty about truth [which] persists even for disambiguated sentences in well-specified contexts.

Mereological theories of natural language therefore unavoidably have vague parts de dicto. Consider the system of the human body. Anyone can point to the forehead, but where does the forehead begin and end? And when one says circulatory system, at what point does one precisely demarcate vein, capillary, and artery? And does the CNS become the PNS at an exact point? No, these artificial boundaries which are given by language are somewhat varied in terms of their precision, and precision is dictated by cultural and teleological concerns.
Even formal mereological theories, like that of a mereotopological theory expressed in a formal system contain vagueness. Certainly moving from natural language systems to an artificial language of a formal system helps. After all, rigorous formal definitions tend to be easy to reduce since they rely heavily on the syntactic properties of the expressions. But ultimately the system has to have a natural language interpretation. Consider that it's possible in topology to have open boundaries based on open sets. (Even more confusing are clopen sets!)
Therefore, when you ask:

Can Mereology account for vagueness as a fundamental property of parts?

Absolutely it does, as any natural language mereological system is unavoidably populated with vague properties of parts, and since ultimately all formal systems bottom out in natural language to be meaningful, the interpretation of mereological systems can be rife with parts that overlap or vague criteria. Let's take a look at Lando's text on Mereology (GB). He says:

[G]iven a vague condition for composition, vagueness could not fail to be inherited by the claim that the fusion[, a joining of parts,] exists. A restriction on composition [could be expressed in] logical language through the definitions of Fusion and Overlap:... ∀xx (φxx ⟺ ∃y(yΣxx))... But if φ is vague and [this formula] holds, the right side of the biconditional... cannot fail to be vague. Moreover, within the right side of the biconditional... at least one subsentential expression should be vague too, because vagueness does not concern sentences only. (pg. 182)

While the details of the notation are a bit difficult to comprehend since they come towards the end of the theory, bearers of vagueness plague all sorts of parts of mereological formal theory. Thus, the true struggle in mereological theories is minimizing vagueness.
Additional resources:

Deconstructing Ontological Vagueness by Matti Eklund: "A theme underlying the discussion will be the distinction between vagueness specifically and indeterminacy more generally (and, relatedly, the distinction between ontological vagueness and ontological indeterminacy). Even if the world is somehow ontologically indeterminate it by no means follows that it is, properly speaking, ontologically vague."
Ontological Paradoxes by Piotr Łukowski (springer.com) "The paradoxes we have analyzed so far have a common property: they do not go beyond the language. The difficulties, which they expose, have intra-linguistic character. Their analysis, and all the more so their solution, does not require any confrontation of thought and reality."


This response is very precise, and I appreciate it. What surprises me (and this is due to my lack of knowledge in the field) is that you say mereology cannot say anything about reality. Is this true? Can't an ontology be expressed mereologically? It is true that this carries the enormous risk of treating reality like a language, but that is a separate problem.

Mereological is a fancy word for "has parts as a system", and that's simply a presumption that something can be divided; the real question is, is that a necessity of the external, physical world, or a limit of the human mind? I have made no claims either way of how it applies to reality. To do so would be to stake out a position between scientific realism and instrumentalism and is related to linguistic relativity...

but if language "carves up reality at the joints" as they say, it is the language that is ambiguous and not the "units of reality". Let's presume natural kinds exist. Then, the kinds are mind-independent, and the ontological relativity is a property of the language. But if ontological primitives are largely determined by the mind, then natural kinds are a sort of intersubjective predisposition, and the fact they are useful, common, and normative is a function of how minds construct them, and thus natural kinds aren't really mind-independent.

Intuitively, I think the dichotomy between realism and instrumentalism is begging to be dissolved, but that's just an extension of the age old problem of reconciling dualism. To become a property dualist is the first step, but the rest is still puzzling, at least to me.

Added a couple of references that emphasize the locus of vagueness as linguistic rather than physical and state that the issue of ontological vagueness is divorced from questions about reality generally.
